# How to get all balance value from two tables using inner join or group by in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

table_name: year
[image: table1]

table_name: month

[image: table2]

expected output:
[image: table3]

I am using the below query for the above output, but i get the unexpected result.

```
SELECT a.id
     , SUM(a.no_of_units_purchase) 
  FROM month a
     , year b 
 WHERE a.id=b.id 
 GROUP 
    by b.id
```

Output for above query:
[image: table4]

Please guide me to get the expected result..

thanks in advance..

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a *left join* instead of a simple *join* as the table month could not contain purchases for a given year. The query that would work is:

```
select year.id,
       year.no_of_units,
       sum(ifnull(month.no_of_units_purchase, 0)) as no_of_units_purchase,
       year.no_of_units - sum(ifnull(month.no_of_units_purchase, 0)) as balance_units
from   year
       left join month on year.id = month.id
group by
       year.id, 
       year.no_of_units
```

Answer (score 0):

An inner join (as you have discovered) only returns cases where there are matches between the 2 tables. You can use an outer join to return all the records in one table and the matching records from the other.

```
SELECT a.id
 , SUM(a.no_of_units_purchase), SUM(IFNULL(b.no_of_units, 0))
 , SUM(a.no_of_units_purchase) - SUM(IFNULL(b.no_of_units, 0))
FROM month a
LEFT JOIN year b 
  ON a.id=b.id 
GROUP by a.id
```

It's not clear from your example whether you need to output cases where there are records in the "year" table which do not have corresponding rows in the "month" table - but this is possible too.

Some DBMS support a "full outer join" which returns all the records from both tables, linking the matching ones. MySQL does not support this directly - but its easy to recreate the behaviour:

```
SELECT a.id
 , SUM(a.no_of_units_purchase), SUM(IFNULL(b.no_of_units, 0))
FROM month a
LEFT JOIN year b 
  ON a.id=b.id 
GROUP by a.id
UNION
SELECT b.id, 0, SUM(b.no_of_units)
FROM year b
LEFT JOIN month a
  ON b.id=a.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
GROUP BY b.id
```